# On the pointwise convergence of generalized Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\{e_k\}$ be a polynomial orthonormal complete basis of $L^2(0,1)$. Let $f:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb R$. The generalized Fourier series of $f$ for the basis $\{e_k\}$, when it exists, is denoted by

$$\forall x \in (0,1), \quad S(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x)$$

$$S_n(x)= \sum_{k=1}^n\langle f, e_k\rangle_{L^2} e_k(x)$$

1) Suppose $f\in L^2(0,1)$. What extra conditions (as minimal as possible) should we put on $f$ to get $\forall x, \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x) =f(x)$ ?

2) Suppose $f\in L^2(0,1)$. What extra conditions (as minimal as possible) should we put on $f$ to get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x)= f(x)$ if $x$ is a continuity point of $f$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x)= \frac{f(x^+)+f(x^-)}{2}$ otherwise ?

3) Suppose $f\in L^2(0,1)$, increasing and left-continuous with right limits everywhere on $(0,1)$. What extra conditions (as minimal as possible) should we put on $f$ to get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x)= f(x)$ if $x$ is a continuity point of $f$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x)= \frac{f(x^+)+f(x^-)}{2}$ otherwise ?

4) Suppose $f\in L^1(0,1)$ and $S(x)$ exists $\forall x \in (0,1)$. What extra conditions (as minimal as possible) should we put on $f$ to get $\forall x, \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x) =f(x)$ ?

5) Suppose $f\in L^1(0,1)$ and $S(x)$ exists $\forall x \in (0,1)$. What extra conditions (as minimal as possible) should we put on $f$ to get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x)= f(x)$ if $x$ is a continuity point of $f$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x)= \frac{f(x^+)+f(x^-)}{2}$ otherwise ?

6) Suppose $f\in L^1(0,1)$, increasing and left-continuous with right limits everywhere on $(0,1)$, and $S(x)$ exists $\forall x \in (0,1)$. What extra conditions (as minimal as possible) should we put on $f$ to get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x)= f(x)$ if $x$ is a continuity point of $f$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n(x)= \frac{f(x^+)+f(x^-)}{2}$ otherwise ?

Any reference that includes proofs about different types of convergences of generalized Fourier series is very welcome.

Comment: I think you are missing the point, the condition is on $e_k$, the complex exponentials are very specific, it is from the way they behave with the derivative that we get that if $f'$ is in $L^2$ then its Fourier series converges in $L^2$ thus in $L^1$ thus the Fourier series of $f=\int f'$ converges uniformly.

Comment: the space $L^2$ is an space of equivalence classes, so it doesn't make sense to talk about pointwise convergence **for all** $x$. We only assume that for any representative of each equivalent class of functions it Fourier representation converges pointwise to it for **almost every** $x\in (0,1)$, not for all $x$

Comment: @reuns I added "polynomial basis"

Comment: @Masacroso This is the whole point of adding conditions. Clearly, you take a $C^\infty(0,1)$ function that is $L^2(0,1)$, its generalized Fourier series is going to converge pointwise to the function itself. I am looking for weaker conditions.

Comment: "Clearly" we have pointwise convergence if $f\in C^\infty$? That's not at all clear to me - how do you prove it?

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence)

Comment: @Masacroso this only holds for the complex exponential basis. I am looking for a general result on a polynomial basis.

Comment: ??? That link talks about standard Fourier series, $e_k(t)=e^{ikt}.  Of course smooth implies convergence for standard Fourier series! The question is about your "non-standard"  Fourier series...

Comment: @W.Volante Huh? _You_ said "Clearly, you take a $C^\infty(0,1)$ function that is $L2(0,1)$, its generalized Fourier series is going to converge pointwise to the function itself.". And now you say you're looking  for  a proof!  If you don't know a proof what makes you so  certain it's true?